# Spring Framework, How to setup a public profile page for each user which can be viewed by anyone?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am currently building a web application using the Spring Framework as well as Hibernate.

Currently, the application is in a state where each user has their own profile page which they can view and edit while logged in.
The profile is generated using data stored about the user in a MySQL database.
The problem comes as this profile page is generated dynamically each time the user visits http://www.xxxxx.com/profile

My goal is for the profile page to be publicly viewable by anyone viewing the site. I intend for people to be able to search and view other user's profiles.

I currently lack the understanding of how I would go about doing this?
I'd greatly appreciate any help or advice to point me in the right direction.

I am still fairly new here, so please don't hesitate to ask for clarification or extra information.

Thanks for the time in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could learn how it is usually done by looking around on a website that already has a similar mechanism, like, say, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5081461/devtony)? Note that this question is off-topic on SO as you didn't even mention *what* your problem is and the only technical (yet irrelevant without any context) information you provided is that you're using Spring, Hibernate and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the /profile page viewable and accessible only for those loggedin users (for example, john)
For an unauthenticated user, you could redirect the /profile to an other /usersview page where you could list all the registered user's pages. And then you could fetch john's profile public page by accessing a path like /profiles/public/john

Comment: Thanks, your answer wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it was good enough to send me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the terrible description of my problem, guess I suck at this. Anyway, I managed to solve this by passing any username to the application via a URL parameter. For Example www.xxxxxxx.com/profile?user=bob.

That username is retrieved from the request in the Controller and passed to a Service in order to retrieve the data for the specified user.

Below is the code inside the Controller that is executed when a request to the above URL is made:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "user")
public ModelAndView showProfileByUsername(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("profile");

    UserBean userBean = loginService.loadUserBeanByUsername(request.getParameter("user"));
    JobSearchUserBean jobSearchUser = jobSearchUserService.getJobSearchUserByUserID(userBean.getId());

    logger.info("DEBUG - JobSearchUser - firstname: " + jobSearchUser.getFirstname() + " surname: " + jobSearchUser.getSurname() + " title: " + jobSearchUser.getTitle() + " location: " + jobSearchUser.getLocation() + " bio: " + jobSearchUser.getBio());

    model.addObject("user_profile", jobSearchUser);
    model.addObject("user_skills", skillsService.getSkillsByJobSearchUserID(jobSearchUser.getId()));
    model.addObject("user_exp", expService.getExperiencesByJobSearchUserID(jobSearchUser.getId()));
    model.addObject("user_qual", qualService.getQualificationsByJobSearchUserID(jobSearchUser.getId()));

    return model;
}
```

Thanks to this it is now possible to view the profile of any user. Not just the logged in user. 
I feel however that there may be better ways to do this.